# How to handle fetch requests in CoreData when you know there are no Entities saved

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, nsfetchrequest

I have an app that I know the first time it runs there will be nothing saved in CoreData. I am trying to check for that scenario like this:

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

```
    let error = NSErrorPointer()

    do{
        let fetchResults = (try! coreDataStack.context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: error))
        print("Count \(fetchResults)")
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

I get a warning saying "Cast from "Int" to unrelated type '[Person]' always fails.

I'm just not sure what I'm missing. I'm sure checking for any Entities in CoreData is a common practice.

Comment: This above syntax is of Swift 1.2, are you using Swift 1.2 or 2? Because `countForFetchRequest` is need  to bound under `try & catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert that into `[Entity]` because the `countForFetchRequest` returns the number of counts. So, you need need to call without casting.

```
let fetchResults = coreDataStack.context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: error)
print("Count \(fetchResults)")
```

Comment: I updated the code in the question and still get 2 warnings as well as a crash "fatal error: unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: The warnings are: "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression, and 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: @icekomo Ok then you can remove `try` and `catch` block, it's unncessary

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this code to get the countForFetchRequest working:` let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

```
    var error: NSError?

    let count = coreDataStack.context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

    if count != NSNotFound {
        print("Count \(count)")
    } else {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }`
```